# @font-face does not work with custom font

Tags: html, css, fonts, prestashop, font-face

I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1nX5_2FQ8g
Generated a folder with font content and css file, I copied the css code to my global.css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Conv_Origram';
src: url('fonts/Origram.eot');
src: local('☺'), url('fonts/Origram.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Origram.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Origram.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1") format("woff"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1") format("truetype"), url("../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1") format("svg");
}
```

I copied the font files to the folder and also tried the location of fontAwesome, which works at my theme. But for my origram font it doesnt work.
I tried just simple html and css on blank domain and it worked, but in my prestashop theme it doesnt.
Thank you for your time

Comment: Some font file types are not supported in certain browsers. For the best compatibility, use true type fonts with the extension .ttf

Comment: I have a font file .ttf there, but still it doesnt work.

Comment: I mean that you have to set it before other types in your CSS declaration.

Comment: It doesn`t work and I tried it with blank domain, just one file with html and css (the same css code) and it works, there must be problem in an implementation to the global.css in presta :/ Help me pls guys.

Answer (score 0):

Font-face requires a little understanding of browser inconsistencies and may require some changes on the web server itself. First thing you have to do is check the console to see if/what messages are being generated. Is it a permissions issue or resource not found....?

Secondly, because each browser is expecting a different font type I would use Font Squirrel to upload your font and then generate the additional files and CSS needed. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

And finally, versions of FireFox and IE will not allow fonts to be loaded cross-domain. You may need to modify your Apache config or .htaccess (Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*")